# Windows 8.1 has locked down "c:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" can't manually install/remove plugins for IE

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-8.1, internet-explorer, plugins

I've discovered that the folder c:\windows\Downloaded Program Files\  where IE puts ActiveX plugins that have been installed ... is seriously locked down in windows 8.1

The situation I'm seeing is that we've got a web scanning plugin that in win 7, one can manually install if they're having issues - just copy the correct DLL into c:\windows\Downloaded Program Files\ then the plugin should work just fine.

And in win 7 it works like that. However, while working with a user who had windows 8.1, he was unable to write to that directory and unable to do anything with permisions for it even when running as local administrator.

I found the same to be true on my windows 8.1 system

REPRO:
on win7 as an administrator, try copying some random innocuous file to 
c:\windows\Downloaded Program Files\

It works fine
Repeat (also as an administrative user) on a machine running Windows 8.1
it won't let you

I recognize that this is likely a security measure to help fight malware... but I'm stymied... is there any simple fix that won't involve hacking the registry, killing a service, or otherwise opening up the PC to major security issues and/or instability?

(I'm ok with "no" but I'd like to ~know~ rather than guess here)

It also begs the question "how in heck to valid plugins get installed there then?"

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I should add that this protection didn't change between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.  The folder always required an Administrator level permission escalation to write to it.

Comment: Ramhound, Fair enough - I guess what's bothering me is that I am running as an administrative user and I appear to have no rights to write to it at all. I can't even see a security tab when viewing properties... same basic setup in windows 7 works fine I can write to it.

Am I missing something silly/stupid?

Comment: This Windows 7 machine using IE11?  If I were to hazard to guess the system attribute is the reason you cannot view the properties on this folder.  [explaination](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Q_24733017.html) but this attribute goes back to Windows XP on this folder.  Copying and pasting active x files in this folder does not actually install them.

Comment: Ramhound, Yes, this is why I was so surprised... win7 machine with all the current patches and same version of IE 11... I'm just so used to things "just working" that I kind of take notice when I'm blocked from doing something I can normally do.

The issue came up because we have a native ActiveX plugin to allow web scanning, and when it fails to download/install for a user, the manual process for install is "copy the dll to the downloaded program files directory and run regsvr32 to register it"

Answer (score 1):

I agree - I have same behaviour under Windows 8.1 when using File Explorer.  I don't know what you can do about that.

However, I find that if I run an *elevated* Command Prompt I am able to successfully `dir/del/copy` on `"C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files"` to manipulate the files there as I need, so perhaps that would do for you/your user?